# Attain div_for feature for <div> tag.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

As `div_for` sets both the `class and id` for the `@object` , i want to attain the same functionality manually for `<div>` tag, such that i can use rails `dom_id` feature on that.

I have tried using with something like `<div id = "@post.id"> </div>` and want to use this 
`$('#<%= dom_id(@post) %>').fadeOut();` on it, but it doesn't work like this as for `div_for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<div id="<%= dom_id(@post) %>">...</div>
```

You're selecting `dom_id(@post)` in your jQuery selector, but not setting that as the ID in the code...